# Is it safe to mix boost locks and std locks?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Is there any gotchas to use Boost mutex with C++11 std locks or the opposite?

For instance, can I lock a `boost::shared_mutex` with `std::unique_lock`. Is it safe to do so?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with doing that, `std::unique_lock` is designed to work with any type that meets [`BasicLockable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable) requirements, which `boost::shared_mutex` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem as both libraries expect and implement the same Lockable/BasicLockable concepts:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Lockable